# Having a relative pronoun

Tags: relative-pronouns

> A woman had bitten off part of her tongue owing to the jump the explosion gave her.

Can a relative pronoun **which** or **that** be understood to be between **jump** and **the explosion**?

> A woman had bitten off part of her tongue owing to the jump which/that the explosion gave her.

.

> She hadn't showed that little bit of imagination I'd credited her with.

Can a relative pronoun **which** or **that** be understood to be between **imagination** and **I'd**?

> She hadn't showed that little bit of imagination which/that I'd credited her with.

With or without the relative pronoun ,does it differ in meaning?

Comment: This isn't your question, but the first sentence is very unnatural - in English we wouldn't usually talk about an explosion "giving someone a jump."  Either the explosion is "giving someone **a scare**" or she is "**jumping at the explosion**."

Answer (score 2):

The relative pronoun is generally omitted when it would be in the accusative case.

> Men must reap the things(which/that) they sow.
>
> A woman had bitten off part of her tongue owing to the jump the explosion gave her.
>   A woman had bitten off part of her tongue owing to the jump(which/that) the explosion gave her.

Do not differ in meaning.

Comment: Thanks, what about the second example , the sentence with **with** at the end of the sentence.